# scripting issue unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code for a cube game. Actually I want this code to run like :
when I press "Space" once it must generate one cube ,currently its generating more than one cube for one time pressed "space" button. 
secondly, when I use arrow keys it must generate cube from that position where I am standing currently, but for time being its just generating cubes from center.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class fire : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "brick" || collision.gameObject.name == "a" || collision.gameObject.name == "b")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public float speed;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.Translate(speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            transform.Translate(speed * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);            
        }
        Vector3 temp = transform.position;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {

            GameObject textObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("ball"));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you can ***not*** use "unityscript". it is deprecated, does not work, and is being removed from Unity.  fortunately c# is actually much easier for the beginner. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try using [Input.GetKeyUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html) or GetKeyDown instead of GetKey.
2. You can invoke  [GameObject.Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) with the Position where you want the Object to be instantiated.

Comment: Muhammad please consider about Object Pooling. It is also good for performance.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Input.GetKeyUp ???

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
            print("space key was released");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html "Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name. Think auto fire." so if you press the key for 1/10th of a second and update is called 60 times a second you'll get about six cubes.

Generally you'd want to tie the object creation to a keydown or keyup event as that will only fire once.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use Input.GetKeyDown("space") to instanciate the gameObject once. This is because it would only return true **during** the frame that you pressed it. the Input.GetKey that you are using will return true **while** you are **still** pressing the button.
So you can do something like this:

```
void Update()
{
   if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")
   {
      GameObject textObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("ball"));
   }
}
```